# Regex to match mathematical expressions

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

I have a regex I intend to use to "tokenize" a mathematical expression like:

```
a + b + 1 + 2

int main() {
    string rxstrIdentifier = "\\b[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\b";
    string rxstrConstant = "\\b\\d+\\b";
    string rxstrRef = "(" + rxstrIdentifier + ")|(" + rxstrConstant + ")"; // identifier or constant

    const regex rxExpr = regex("^(" + rxstrRef + ")(.*)$"); // {x} [{+} {y}]*
    //const regex rxSubExpr = regex("^\\s*([+])\\s*(" + rxstrRef + ")(.*)$"); // {+} {x} [...]

    string test = "b + a + 1";
    cmatch res;
    regex_search(test.c_str(), res, rxExpr);
    cout << "operand: " << res[1] << endl;
    cout << "res: " << res[2] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is operand and res gives just b in the example. I expected

```
operand: b
res: + a + 1
```

Used to work in another similar regex ...

```
const regex Parser::rxExpr = regex("^(\\w+)((\\s*([+])\\s*(\\w+))*)$"); // {x} [{+} {y}]*
const regex Parser::rxSubExpr = regex("^\\s*([+])\\s*(\\w+)(.*)$"); // {+} {x} [...]
```

Comment: may i suggest to rather implement a real parser instead of a set of regexes. if you extend your project further a real parser is going to be a lot less painful to maintain.

Comment: Thats what I suggested but I feel the team doesnt like it. Its a school project ... so I think its OK to also try regex for now ...

Comment: Is there any chance that the complexity of the strings you are trying to tokenize is going to increase? Because if so, move to a parser sooner rather than later. Complex regular expressions tend not to be fast or maintainable; there are many lexer and parser generators out there that allow for both those things.

Comment: There are 2 parts to this project ... I intend to use Boost::Spirit in the next part where the complexity is increased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexes don't appear to allow for the whitespace in the string. `\b` matches word boundaries, but boundaries have zero width so nothing's consuming the spaces between the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Use (?:pattern) group:

```
string rxstrRef = "(?:" + rxstrIdentifier + ")|(?:" + rxstrConstant + ")"; // identifier or constant
```

This eliminates the impact on the search results